# How do you make a window to fill the entire screen?

Tags: ruby, shoes, maximize

Can someone give me a pointer on how to make a window in Shoes to fill the entire screen?  I am looking to have a window that is akin to Writeroom.  Thanks.

Comment: @David It's a teaching programming language: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoes_(GUI_toolkit)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be possible right now, sadly.